# Vimscript read line under cursor

Tags: vim

I made a compiler window for vim using vim 8.1s terminal feature.
It shows me the output of the compiler in case any happened.
But now I would like to just press enter on the line of an error inside a terminal window and then instantly open that file inside the main code window, similar to how most editors do it.
For that, I would need to be able to read the current line under the cursor to check whether it is a properly formatted error and if it is going to that file instantly.
So how can I read the current line under the cursor inside a terminal output window?

Comment: You may be interested in `:h write-compiler-plugin`.
Which command do you execute to compile? Can you provide a short sample of the output of the compiler containing valid errors?

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html

Comment: Ill have a look thanks

Comment: This is what quickfix is for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terminal is a new feature, but Vim has had compilation ([`:help :make`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Amake)) and error parsing functionality ([`:help quickfix`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#quickfix)) almost from the start. Vim understands the output of many common [`:compiler`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acompiler)s, and you can define your own one ([`:help write-compiler-plugin`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#write-compiler-plugin)), too.

So, if yours is a proper compiler that has regular, parseable output, that would be the recommended way to go.

#### working with the terminal

On the other hand, if you have good reasons to stick to your original plan, that is possible, too. A terminal buffer in the end works like other (text) buffers inside Vim. With a mapping, you first need to break out of terminal mode (cp. [`:help Terminal-mode`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/terminal.txt.html#Terminal-mode)). Then, a Vimscript can extract text as usual:

- obtain the current line with `:let line = getline('.')`
- grab the work under the cursor with `:let word = expand('<cword>')`